# how to find webpages which link to some specific page?

Tags: search-engine

Just wondering if there's any way to search all web pages which link to some specific url? For example, all web pages containing link to example.com? Thanks

Comment: You wanna search all web pages on the WWW? Are you sure you dispose with the proper hardware to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably might want to explore the [Google Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) which allows you to use Google search results in your programs.

Comment: Hi @Darin, Can you specify exactly how to Google Search API to achieve this?